# Angular adds style animations to DOM on Safari browser

Tags: angular, animation, safari, angular-material

I've built an application in *Angular 7* using *Angular Material* framework. Everything looks good in *Chrome*, but now I want to enable access with *Safari* and to my surprise a lot of elements are looking very odd. Below is a picture of some icons for example. The same happens with inputs and buttons. (seems to be some kind of *focus-overlay*).

[image: icons]

After a while I figured out that it has something to do with *animations*. Because on *Safari* I see these weird `style="animation"` attributes added. When I remove them in developer tools, everything is looking good again. Now, I have no idea how these animations got there and can't find any related issue while googling. I have enabled most of the default stuff from *polyfills.ts* file.

How can I fix this issue? When I look at the *Angular Material* documentation on *Safari*, everything looks fine there.

This is how my *DOM* looks in *Safari*:

[image: code]

Answer (score 1):

Safari seems to frequently have issues with Angular Material judging by a quick google search.

There seem to be a few packages that allow you to partially disable animations like [this](https://codebase.cloudaix.com/allgemein/partially-disable-angular-material-animations/) one. Which makes use of the [`NoopAnimationsModule`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/animations/NoopAnimationsModule).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried to disable all the animations, now the initial issue is gone. However, I would still like to find a solution which allows me to keep animations enabled.